# Flask + gunicorn proxy setup?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I try to wire Flask, gunicorn and nginx together but it ends up with 400 Bad request and 500 Errors.
Hope that anyone can help.

**nginx conf**

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location /Hello {
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
}
```

**wsgi.py snippet:**

```
from app import app

app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8081)
```

**app.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Not A Secret Anymore By Now"

@app.route('/Hello')
def hello():
  return("Hello")


#if __name__ == "__main__":
#  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

**run cmd**

```
export FLASK_APP=app
export FLASK_ENV=development
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8081 wsgi:app
```

**test cases**

1. curl http://localhost/           >>> returns nginx homepage
2. curl http://localhost/Hello      >>> returns 404 Not found
3. curl http://localhost:8000/      >>> returns nginx homepage
4. curl http://localhost:8000/Hello >>> returns 502 Bad Gateway
5. curl http://localhost:8081       >>> return Connection refused

I try to get the test cases working, but have not clue why the errors appears, (nginx is restarted).

Thank you.

Comment: Updated, def hello was returning 'Hello';

Comment: When using uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8081; curl localhost:8000 fails.

Comment: When using prox_pass 127.0.0.1:8081; curl localhost:8000 return Nginx page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems here...

Your view function ends without a return statement, which is probably the cause of the first 500 error.  Better use:

```
@app.route('/Hello')
def hello():
  print("Hello")
  return 'success'
```

Also as you metntion `uwsgi.py` is emtpy, there's no app object to import there.  Best point the gunicorn command at a valid app object:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8081 app:app
```

Also the nginx location block expects the request to go to `http://example.com/Hello/Hello`.  So better make the location block like the following.  (Also ensure the port is the same one you provded to gunicorn's `--bind` flag).

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
}
```

Here I've also used `proxy_pass` as per the [gunicorn deployment (with nginx) docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#nginx-configuration).

Now the request should work:

```
# Direct to app server...
curl -i  http://localhost:8081/Hello
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gunicorn/20.0.4
# ...
success
```

and also:

```
# Via nginx:
curl -i http://localhost/Hello
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
...
success
```

Beware that running gunicorn on all interfaces (0.0.0.0) means external requests could reach the app server directly (bypassing nginx) if no firewall is in place to prevent this.  Might be worth instead binding gunicorn to the local interface: `--bind 127.0.0.1:8081`.

Also be careful in general, there's lots of ways to make security slip-ups when configuring stuff like this yourself.  Good luck.

Comment: curl -i http://localhost/Hello
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

Comment: url http://localhost:8081/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8081: Connection refused